# Youtube - get player into fullscreen by using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, fullscreen

Is it possible to set Youtube video player to full-screen mode by using Javascript ?

I have content script (Chrome extension) that does the following:

```
 var e = new MouseEvent("click", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});

//ytp-button ytp-size-toggle-large is the full-screen div on Youtube page (in button role)
document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-button ytp-size-toggle-large')[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

But the player will not go into full-screen mode.